# count data from multiple year and group by month

Tags: mysql

I want to make chart, here's my table;

```
 mrp
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2011-10-xx |
| 2011-12-xx |
| 2012-01-xx |
| 2012-05-xx |
| 2013-01-xx |
| 2013-02-xx |
+------------+
```

I want to count data from last 3 years, group by month, here's what I'm trying to achieve;

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| quarty | 2011   | 2012   | 2013   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|jan-mar | 0      | 1      | 2      |
|apr-jun | 0      | 1      | 0      |
|jul-sept| 0      | 0      | 0      |
|oct-dec | 2      | 0      | 0      |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I tried this;

```
select case when month(date) between 1 and 3 then 'Jan-Mar'
when month(date) between 4 and 6 then 'Apr-Jun'
when month(date) between 7 and 9 then 'Jul-Sept'
else 'Oct-Dec' end 'quarty',
SUM(year(date) = 2011) AS `2011`,
SUM(year(date) = 2012) AS `2012`,
SUM(year(date) = 2013) AS `2013`
from `mrp` where year(date) >= 2011
group by 'quarty'
```

but somehow it only show **'Oct-Dec' in 2011, 2012, and 2013**; is there any way to make it?

Note: I already find another query how to show **all month** but **only in one year**, and I can't sort it correctly, It show apr-jun first, then jan-mar, jul-sept, and oct-dec, how can I sort it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`QUARTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) function to do the work for you.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN QUARTER(`date`) = 1 THEN 'Jan-Mar'
            WHEN QUARTER(`date`) = 2 THEN 'Apr-Jun'
            WHEN QUARTER(`date`) = 3 THEN 'Jul-Sep'
            WHEN QUARTER(`date`) = 4 THEN 'Oct-Dec'
       END AS `Quarty`,
       SUM(year(`date`) = 2011) AS `2011`,
       SUM(year(`date`) = 2012) AS `2012`,
       SUM(year(`date`) = 2013) AS `2013`
FROM `mrp`
WHERE year(`date`) >= 2011
GROUP BY QUARTER(`date`)
```

[Live Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45ff8/14/0)

Answer (score 0):

this is just from 2011, but you can add table from 2012 and 2013 by your self

```
select
case
  when monthvalue=1 then 'Jan-Mar'
  when monthvalue=2 then 'Apr-Jun'
  when monthvalue=3 then 'Jul-Sep'
  when monthvalue=4 then 'Oct-Dec'
end as period,
t2011.x as freq2011 from
(SELECT CEIL(MONTH(date)/3) as monthVALUE,count(*) as x
FROM mrp
where year(date)=2011
GROUP BY monthVALUE) t2011;
```